# Laravel - belongsToMany return error on changed table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I replace existing relation?
At this moment, I have tables:
**requirements**
[image]
etc.
**user_requirement**
[image]

And I have this relation in **User** model:

```
public function requirements(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Requirement', 'user_requirement')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Now I created new table - **activities**:
[image]

And now, how can I set `ID` from **activities** for `requirement_id` in this relation in model?

**EDIT:** I do somethink like this:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Activities', 'user_requirement', 'requirement_id', 'ID' )->withTimestamps();
```

But when I in try to do in view (**$req->ID** is **Activity ID**):

```
@if( !$user->activities()->get()->contains( $req->ID ) ) {
  No activity
@else
  Yes activity
@endif
```

I'm getting always **FALSE**

Answer (score 0):

```
public function requirements(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Requirement', 'id', 'requirement_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: Table 'my_database.id' doesn't exist